# How can I convert XWPFDocument to PDF

Tags: java, apache-poi, pdf-conversion, xwpf

I'm having an issue in converting DOCX file to PDF. Here's the code:

```
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

File docxFile         = new File("somepath\Sample.docx");
File pdfFile          = new File("somepath\Sample.pdf");
PdfOptions pdfOptions = PdfOptions.create();
InputStream  is       = new FileInputStream(docxFile);
OutputStream pdfOut   = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
XWPFDocument xwpfDoc  = new XWPFDocument(is);
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(xwpfDoc, pdfOut, pdfOptions);
```

Here's the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/ganymede] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid integer value: 739.0000152587891] with root cause
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid integer value: 739.0000152587891
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase$ValueOutOfRangeValidationContext.invalid(XmlObjectBase.java:328)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolder.lex(JavaIntegerHolder.java:50)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolderEx.set_text(JavaIntegerHolderEx.java:40)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.update_from_wscanon_text(XmlObjectBase.java:1180)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_dated(XmlObjectBase.java:1319)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolder.getBigIntegerValue(JavaIntegerHolder.java:58)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTTabStopImpl.getPos(Unknown Source)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.canApplyTabStop(PdfMapper.java:849)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.getTabStop(PdfMapper.java:824)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitTabs(PdfMapper.java:738)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitTabs(PdfMapper.java:111)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitRun(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:798)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitRun(PdfMapper.java:524)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitRun(PdfMapper.java:111)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitRuns(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:617)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitParagraphBody(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:442)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitParagraph(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:333)
```

My Apache POI version is 3.9 and the PDF Converter is 2.0.0.

Another note is that this document is generated using a WYSIWYG editor. That might be the cause why it sets irregular values for the docx properties before converting it to PDF?

What do you think caused this and how should I approach it? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the `Sample.docx` coming from? According the error, there is a tab stop position `<w:tab w:pos="739.0000152587891">` set. But that is invalid because tab stop position must be integer in `Office Open XML`. So `Sample.docx` contains invalid `XML`.

Comment: [Apache POI 3.9 is almost 10 years old now!](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.9) What happens if you upgrade to something vaguely recent?

Comment: @AxelRichter its bytes came from the export module of the WYSIWYG editor. The document also has tables. Can the PDF Converter handle docx files with tables? That may be the cause for non-integer values

Comment: Then the "export module of the WYSIWYG editor" makes something wrong. According `Office Open XML` specs, tab position values must be integer in measure unit `twips ` (twentieth of an inch point).